# c# web browser url update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have created a web browser in c# 
[image]

this was what i get when i opened my web browser and typed google. Then i searched google for something 
the result was like this 
[image]

But the url wasn't updated in address bar. How to update the address bar when user click on a link on any website in my web browser
In the first image the url was google.com
In the second image url was https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab like that some thing but it wasn't updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events.
I think you can use Navigating event to detect when user starts search or navigates to another page.

Answer (score 1):

You must update the textbox on top with the URL of the WebBrowserControl, using the `webBrowser1_Navigating` event.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
      textbox1.text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Form_Load must contain this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            web = new WebBrowser();
            web.Navigated += web_Navigated;
        }
```

and this function:

```
private void web_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = web.Url.ToString();
        }
```